# How to get rid of popup ads?

Tags: javascript, popup, ads

Today I woke up and find out, two of my sites are showing a pop-under advertisments. I tracked it with http://tools.pingdom.com and find the javascript which is causing it. banners?tid=SWTMPOP&tagid=2

and this is where it leads me to, http://clktag.com/adServe/banners?tid=SWTMPOP&tagid=2 im not using RevenueHits on my site

How can I find out where it is and how to get rid of it.

Comment: Take the infected servers off line. Put replacements with known good in their place. Change the passwords. Update to the latest versions (with security fixes) for all the software you have installed on them. Run a malware scanner over your workstation. The investigate how the compromised servers were compromised.

Comment: Is there a way, by adding a code or something, to prevent opening the pop-ups?

Comment: If there are popups on your site that you didn't put there then either your workstation or your server is **under someone else's control and they are using their power for evil**. Adding code is not going to fix anything. You need to control your own computer again.